# When do auto-save checkpoints activate?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

When I completed the side-mission, [Water and Honesty](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Water_and_Honesty), I received money from the stanger and +Fame; I was riding fast towards MacFarlane's ranch to save the game, during which power went off in my apartment.

Now when I restarted playing when the power resumed, I couldn't see this side mission appearing again. I assume that my PS3 saved this side-quest as completed. Now the question is, would it have saved my increased fame and money? I didn't see any *Saving...* animation on the left top corner of my TV.

Likewise, when I completed [Spare the Rod, Spoil the Bandit](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Spare_the_Rod,_Spoil_the_Bandit), I looted the bodies of the bandits I'd neutralised, also my honor was increased moments back when the Marshal left me. With these I was going to save the game, while couple of men were chasing another, when I shot one of them, it turned out that they're lawmen, so a bounty was set on me; I reloaded the last auto saved game and it didn't show this mission any more.

The questions are: When does auto-save kick in? What all does it save? When are fame,  honor and money saved? When are mission (both main and side) completions saved?

Answer (score 2):

My answers are based on information found at [the wiki](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Save).

In answer to your questions:

> When does auto-save kick in?

Auto saving happens after missions are completed, or when changing game settings. The definition of [mision](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Missions_in_Redemption) included both "Water and Honesy" (and all other Stranger Side-Missions) and "Spare the Rod, Spoil the Bandit" (offered by Leigh Johnson).

> What all does it save?

The wiki does not make a distinction between a manual save and an auto-save.

> When are fame, honor and money saved?

I would expect (based on the above) that they are save for either type of save.

> When are mission (both main and side) completions saved?

After any Mission, the game will Auto-Save. I would take this to mean that mission completions are stored in the last auto-save.